# SQLite "no such table"

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I've made an Adnroid program in Eclipse that reads a csv file and inputs the info into an SQLite database, and using

```
dbCursor = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_ITEMTYPE, KEY_QUANTITY},  null, null, null, null, null);  

    int iRow = dbCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iType = dbCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEMTYPE);
    int iQuantity = dbCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);

        for(dbCursor.moveToFirst(); !dbCursor.isAfterLast(); dbCursor.moveToNext()){
            allData = allData + " " + dbCursor.getString(iRow) + "\t " + dbCursor.getString(iType) + "\t\t\t " + dbCursor.getString(iQuantity) + "\n";      
        }
```

and then printing out allData in a textview box has worked just fine.

Then I wanted to use

```
dbCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT KEY_ROWID , SUM(KEY_ITEMTYPE) FROM DATABASE_TABLE GROUP BY KEY_ROWID", null);          
for(dbCursor.moveToFirst(); !dbCursor.isAfterLast(); dbCursor.moveToNext()){

    allDataSum = allDataSum + " " + dbCursor.getString(0);
} //I know this will probably not print what I want correctly but that's a problem for another day
```

When I try to print this I get the error "10-25 22:06:35.016: I/Database(1911): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: DATABASE_TABLE".

I then opened DDMS File Explorer and copied the database onto my desktop and then tried viewing the database with a command tool but again got an error, "SQL error: no such table: inventory".

How can the emulator show me what I want to see from .query() (but not from .rawQuery) when apparently there is no table in the database? Everything about I use the query and rawQuery is identical, so it's not a case of not opening the db for rawQuery or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're using a static variables named DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID, and KEY_ITEMTYPE containing your actual names.  When you use this with rawQuery, you'll have to do

```
dbCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_ROWID + ", SUM(" + KEY_ITEMTYPE + ") FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " GROUP BY " + KEY_ROWID, null);
```

Notice that when you make the query using `database.query` you don't have these variables in quotes, that's why it works.

Comment: Good thinking, I changed it but that just created another problem. I defined the column names as static variables as I changed the entire thing to

Comment: I just noticed that and edited my answer to include all the variables.

Comment: oops, accidental enter. Anyway, 

I changed it but that just created another problem. Long story short, when I tried making it

dbCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + DATABASE_TABLE +, null);

I got the error "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from String to int"

but it's defined in the following way:

 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "inventory";

any ideas?

Comment: You have a spare + at the end of your string.  Try `dbCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + DATABASE_TABLE, null);`

Comment: That worked, had the same problem with the original one, thanks. How can I print
`dbCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_ROWID + ", SUM(" + KEY_ITEMTYPE + ") FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " GROUP BY " + KEY_ROWID, null);`
?
I tried doing it similarly as the first one but I get the error "10-26 00:15:04.855: E/CursorWindow(19014): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 5, numColumns = 2"

Comment: You need to name your sum column.  For example: `"SELECT rowid, SUM( itemtype ) as sum FROM table GROUP BY rowid"` or, using variables, `", SUM(" + KEY_ITEMTYPE + ") AS sum FROM "`  The column containing the sum is now called "sum" in your result.

Comment: But don't I have to define it in the program somehow so that I can print it? And on a sidenote, don't I have to make a new column for the grouped together rows?

Comment: No, just access it by whatever you named it in the SQL query.  `dbCursor.getInt( dbCursor.getColumnIndex( "sum" ) );`

Comment: Brilliant! I've got it working exactly like I as I was going for. Thank you very much @Ralgha !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the SUM() aggregate is causing you trouble, but you can double check the table's existence using the sqlite command line and the ".tables" command:

```
sqlite3 DATABASE
SQLite version 3.7.8 2011-09-19 14:49:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sql>.tables
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that statement