# How to resolve an SQLLite "no such table" error?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, database-schema

**Overview:**
I'm using SQLLite to query an existing database in a Windows Phone 8.1 solution. I've adapted this [solution](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/55275a/windows-phone-8-1-sqlite-how-to-store-data-in-database/) to read the database data back to my project. But *when I call ToList() using the DB connection I get a no such database error*.

So far I've attached the database file and my DBHelper class uses the following code to query the data back:

```
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            //No such table error thrown here ->
            List<ZoneInfo> zoneInfo = dbConn.Table<ZoneInfo>().ToList<ZoneInfo>();
            ObservableCollection<ZoneInfo> zoneInfoCollection = new ObservableCollection<ZoneInfo>(zoneInfo);
            return zoneInfoCollection;
        }
```

This is the complete [DBHelper](https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/2e36cf10d52efdb7128e) class which reference the existing DB file from my solution and copies it to the device's local folder. The DB file itself is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlcEkJ1DNI1cHUydWtUcmF1Rkk/view?usp=sharing).

Debugging steps:

- I reviewed the ZoneInfo class properties to check that they match with the type/name each field in the DB schema below, and they match.
- The dbPath name matches the attached database name so that's not the issue either.
- I also found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078835/sqlite-no-such-table) related to SQLLite on Android which suggests it could be an issue with my query on the table.
- I also inspected the dbconn variable and it shows me more info on the error:

[image]
**Question:**

What steps should I take to debug the SQLLite "no table" error further?

**Exception Detail:**
The exact detail of the exception is as follows which tells me there is no such ZoneInfo table:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=no such table: ZoneInfo
  Source=Parking Tag Picker WRT
  StackTrace:
       at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2(IntPtr db, String query)
       at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare()
       at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__0`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[T]()
       at SQLite.TableQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Parking_Tag_Picker_WRT.Helpers.DatabaseHelper.ReadZones(String dbPath)
       at Parking_Tag_Picker_WRT.ViewModel.TagRequestViewModel.InitZoneInfoAsync()
       at Parking_Tag_Picker_WRT.TagRequestPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  InnerException:
```

**ZoneInfo Class: (maps the DB data to a class)**

```
public class ZoneInfo
{

    //The ObjectId property is marked as the Primary Key  
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    [Column("results_list_objectId")]
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    [Column("results_list_zone")]
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }

    [Column("results_list_tariff_ph")]
    public int? TariffPH  { get; set; }

    [Column("results_list_tariff_pd")]
    public int? TariffPD { get; set; }

    [Column("results_list_restrictions")]
    public string Restrictions { get; set; }

    [Column("results_list_days_of_operation")]
    public string DaysOpen { get; set; }

    [Column("results_list_hours_of_operation")]
    public string HoursOpen { get; set; }



    public ZoneInfo() 
    {

    }


    public ZoneInfo(string objectId, string zoneName, int tariffPH, int tariffPD, 
        string restrictions, string daysOpen, string hoursOpen )
    {

        ObjectId = objectId;
        ZoneName = zoneName;
        TariffPH = tariffPH;
        TariffPD = tariffPD;
        Restrictions = restrictions;
        DaysOpen = daysOpen;
        HoursOpen = hoursOpen;
    }



}
```

**DB Schema:**

[image]

DB Location in solution:

[image]

Comment: I dont find ZoneInfo table in your database.

Comment: Ok there is none, that is the name of the POCO class that my db should map to. Should the <ZoneInfo> be named the same as my db file name? DublinCityCouncilTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your github repo your `dbpath` represents just the relative path right `Databases/DublinCityCouncilTable.db`. Now for creating your connection you would need to provide the absolute path to your copied datatbase which would be

```
using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,@"Databases\DublinCityCouncilTable.db"), true))
```

Comment: I had another look at my code..need to rework it following your example above. I'll mark this as accepted and post another question if needed.

Comment: I posted a new question following on from your edits - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808724/how-to-resolve-an-incorrect-path-to-sqlite-database