# How to correct database field mappings in SQLite?

Tags: c#, database, data-binding, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I've attached an SQLite database to my Windows Phone 8.1 project. The connection is working but the results returned from the database are null.

Previously I posted a [question on the null bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902785/how-to-resolve-null-bindings-on-sqlite-query) of my query. But the answer suggested hasn't resolved the issue of a null result being returned, which is why I'm re-posting the question.

***Debugging***: Stepping through the SQLlite class I can see that the bindings are null although I don't see any reason for that considering the types in my DB schema and the associated field mappings in `ZoneInfo.cs`.

[image]

I query the database as follows which should map each field to my class ZoneInfo below.

```
            using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, AppDBPath), true))
            {
                List<ZoneInfo> zoneInfo = dbConn.Query<ZoneInfo>("select * from " + tableName).ToList<ZoneInfo>();
                ObservableCollection<ZoneInfo> zoneInfoCollection = new ObservableCollection<ZoneInfo>(zoneInfo);
                return zoneInfoCollection;
            }
```

**Question:**

How can I correct my database mappings so that the query result isn't empty?

```
**ZoneInfo.cs (mapping class for DB fields)**

public class ZoneInfo
{

    //The ObjectId property is marked as the Primary Key  
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    [Column("objectId")]
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    [Column("zone")]
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }

    [Column("tariff_ph")]
    public float TariffPH  { get; set; }

    [Column("tariff_pd")]
    public float TariffPD { get; set; }

    [Column("restrictions")]
    public string Restrictions { get; set; }

    [Column("days_of_operation")]
    public string DaysOpen { get; set; }

    [Column("hours_of_operation")]
    public string HoursOpen { get; set; }



    public ZoneInfo() 
    {

    }


    public ZoneInfo(string objectId, string zoneName, int tariffPH, int tariffPD, 
        string restrictions, string daysOpen, string hoursOpen )
    {

        ObjectId = objectId;
        ZoneName = zoneName;
        TariffPH = tariffPH;
        TariffPD = tariffPD;
        Restrictions = restrictions;
        DaysOpen = daysOpen;
        HoursOpen = hoursOpen;
    }



}
```

Query Result: (You can see that the result of the query's field's are all null which isn't the case in the database:

[image]

The DB schema is as follows and this is a link to the [DB file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlcEkJ1DNI1V1duR2V1aXRLUE0/view) for testing:

[image]

Comment: Your prev [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35808724/2898399) contained a sample repo. On executing it found your `ReadZones` reading and binding correct value. So are you sure its binding schema error not some other changes that you might have made.

Comment: @Jerin The DBHelper code is the same since I posted that question..so not sure what the difference could be. My current repo is here https://github.com/BrianJVarley/Parking-Tag-Sms-Sender/blob/master/Parking%20Tag%20Picker%20WRT/Helpers/DataBaseHelper.cs

Comment: Tested your repo I am able to receive the values of your database inside `TagRequestViewModel` class, `InitZoneInfoAsync()` method returns value for line `var zoneResult = _dbHelper.ReadZones(tableName);` So your `ObservableCollection<ZoneInfo> ReadZones` is getting called and working fine. Could you pls specify where you are getting null value?

Comment: @Jerin I set a breakpoint on the ReadZone() in the DbHelper class. When I check the value of each ZoneInfo item in the returned zoneInfoCollection the field values are null. Can you post a screenshot of the values you see returned in TagRequestViewModel?

Comment: Here is the [Image link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=72A2505C9C6FA57C!4946&authkey=!AFXyeZO2uayIIYE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng) As you can see I am getting 5 values returned. I just downloaded your repo and ran it didnt change anything.

Comment: @Jerin finally solved it..my phone had an old version of the Database copied to it from earlier with different field types. I downloaded the source from Github and it's working fine. :)

Comment: Cool bro so write this as answer and award yourself point or delete this question as its similar to your other question and post answer there. Also side note its better to uninstal your app completely before you deploy to your device to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 0):

The schema error causing the null mapping bindings, was the result of stale SQLLite database being referenced on the device.

Deleting the app from the phone and rebuilding the app via Visual Studio caused the database to be redeployed to the file system with the updated correct mappings. :)

```
1.From the Start screen, swipe left to display the Apps list. Alternatively from the Start screen, tap the right arrow (located in the lower-right).
2.Touch and hold an app.
3.Tap uninstall.
4.Tap yes.
```